# Yii2: How to access parameters in template mail?

Tags: php, yii2

I have the following code:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('layouts/html', [
                'name' => $this->name,
                'email' => $this->email,
                'subject' => $this->subject,
                'message' => $this->body])
                ->setTo($this->email)
                ->setFrom([$this->email])
                ->setSubject($this->subject)
                ->send();
```

How can I access the name, email, subject and message in layout/html.php?

Comment: How can you fixed this, am also facing the same problem

Comment: facing same problem. i can't solve it. please help how you solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple you can access name, email, subject and message with `$` sign.

```
$name, $email, $subject, $message
```

Comment: I added template with code:<div><strong>Name: </strong> <?= $name; ?></div>
    <div><strong>Email: </strong> <?= $email; ?></div>
 <div><strong>Subject: </strong> <?= $subject; ?></div>
 <div><strong>Content: </strong> <?= $message; ?></div> but log: Undefined variable: name, email, subject, message

Comment: are you using `yii\swiftmailer\Mailer` ?

Comment: Parameter `message` and other variable in the mail view reserved for the mail message instance. Try to change it.

`'name1' => $this->name,
'email1' => $this->email,
'subject1' => $this->subject,
'message1' => $this->body`

Comment: Access it using $name1, $email1, $subject1, $message1

Comment: Thank you Jayson, i fixed them :D

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you need to replace name of template.
Becouse **layouts/html** does not need to be explicitly specified.

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('mytemplate',
    ['name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'subject' => $this->subject,
        'message' => $this->body])
    ->setTo($this->email)
    ->setFrom([$this->email])
    ->setSubject($this->subject)
    ->send();
```

Sample content of **mail/mytemplate.php** :

```
<?php
echo "$subject<br> $name<br> $email<br> $message";
```

And take default content for **mail/layouts/html.php** [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/mail/layouts/html.php)