# Yii2 email template problems

Tags: email, yii2

Hello I have two problems with email creation.

the first is that the footer is duplicated:

```
<div class="footer">With kind regards, <?= Yii::$app->name ?> team</div>
```

Printing two times the same text

the second is about variables:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/mail/layouts/html', 
                                ['content' => $text,
                                'name'=>'the name',
```

and in view template I just try to get $name

```
$name
```

and the error is:

```
Undefined variable: name
```

The same happen with $image but not with $content

I use swiftmailer and this is my confuguration:

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => true,
    ],
```

useFileTransport is set true but i think is not problem

this is the complete code for send email

```
 Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/mail/layouts/html', 
                                ['content' => $text,
                                'name'=>'the name',
                                'image' => 'path/to/images/image.png',
                                ])
        ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
        ->setTo($email)
        ->setSubject($subject)  
        ->send();
```

Thank to all

Gabriele

Comment: Could you post email template (e.g @app/mail/layouts/html). As for the seconds problem - what happens if you change the order of variables, for example, put 'name' before 'content'?

Comment: the email template is the basic from yii2 app, i just add one parameter for testing, but now i am asking myself if the problem is because i generating the email from model, by the way is sending

Comment: it is wired because i put the silent @ and is working, some solution?

Answer (score 0):

first problem :
maybe there's another file included in other file where that's file included in email layouts, check it again.

second problem :
you can disable error notice in php.ini or if you want to fast just add @ before the variable.
example :
**$name** change to **@$name**

for the same error you just add @ at beginning variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you need to replace name of template.
Becouse **layouts/html** does not need to be explicitly specified.
See my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42960246/1932494